# React re-render Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am creating a small React application and I have encountered a problem on `setState({})` function. It appears that `setstate({})` doesn't re-render the component with other props in my case.

```
export default class datelist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataListArray: [],
      currentState: "",
      dataArray: [],
      date: "",
      flag: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
      Meteor.subscribe("userEntries");
      Meteor.subscribe("dateEntries");
      let cursor = userEntries.find().fetch();
      if (cursor.length !== 0) {
        this.setState({
          dataArray: cursor
        });
      }
    });
  }

  renderData() {
    if (!(this.state.dataListArray.length === 0)) {
      console.log(this.state.dataListArray);
      return this.state.dataListArray[0].dates.map(function(date, index) {
        console.log(date, index);
        return <DateListItem key={index} date={date} />;
      });
    }
  }

  renderComponent(event) {
    console.log("Select Change");
    let date = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      date: date,
      flag: true
    });
  }

  getCursor(event) {
    let cursor = dateEntries.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() }).fetch();
    this.setState({
      dataListArray: cursor,
      currentState: event.target.value
    });
    // render just the components that have the same date
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          onClick={this.getCursor.bind(this)}
          onChange={this.renderComponent.bind(this)}
        >
          {this.renderData()}
        </select>
        {/*<p>{this.state.currentState}</p>*/}
        {this.state.flag ? (
          <Datalist data={this.state.dataArray} date={this.state.date} />
        ) : (
          <span />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The purpose of the `flag` state variable is to make sure that the `Datalist` component is rendered with a correct date value. Each time when the user selects a new date from the select box the `Datalist` component should be re-rendered with a new date prop.

In my case it is rendered just once. I have checked the `renderComponent()` function and it gets called each time I change the value in the select box, but it appears that `setState({})` doesn't re-render the component with new props.

Comment: `props` are the values passed into the component. You don't seem to use any props, is that intentional? You also don't have a `this.renderData` in the code you have included in your question. Could you include that?

Comment: @Tholle the renderData() function is used to retrieve another component. It basically retrieves all the "date" values from the database. I know what props are and I have passed a "data" prop which is an array retrieved from the database and a "date" prop which is the date which the user selects. Each time the onChange event is fired the function by calling setState({}) should re-render the component and Datalist should be called with a new date prop. In my case it is rendered just once, afterwards when I select another value the component is still the same.

Comment: Is `let cursor = dateEntries.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() }).fetch();` in your `getCursor` method synchronous?

Comment: @Tholle I am pretty sure it is.

Comment: All of your child functions shouldn't have direct access to `this` component? You're going to have to bind them all in your constructor or use arrow functions so they have access to the component. Correct it by adding `const getCursor = this.getCursor.bind(this);` and `const renderComponent = this.renderComponent.bind(this);` and `const renderData = this.renderData.bind(this);` in your construct

Comment: @Win it should be `this.getCursor = this.getCursor.bind(this)`

Comment: @st4rl00rd ahh you're correct, this heat is getting to me!